# Content getting truncated when TypeTexting to word document

Tags: powershell, ms-word

When I try to TypeText a long text file to word document the content gets truncated by the 3200 character, with a total of 27 pages, even though the full content is something like 6000 characters and 60 pages long when I paste manually. Here is my code:

```
$Source1 = Get-Content -Path FileSystem::C:\Users\My_user\Desktop\file.txt -Raw;
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application;
$Word.Visible = $True;
$Document = $Word.Documents.Add();
$Selection = $Word.Selection;
$Selection.TypeText($source1);
```

Comment: Does $Selection.Text = $source1 have a similar limitation? (haven’t tested)

Comment: Hey @slightlysnarky, it worked too. No limitation so far. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW I suspect the problem with .TypeText is that it may do soemthing like "generate a Windows keyboard event for every character", and Word could well lose some of those events, even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.typetext) doesn't mention a length limit, although [this forum post](https://microsoft.public.word.vba.general.narkive.com/VVnoW8Kx/string-limit-when-using-selection-typetext) suggests that it is 64KB.

While that doesn't explain your problem with only `6,000` characters, consider using the [`.InsertFile` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertfile) instead (untested):

```
$Selection.InsertFile('C:\Users\My_user\Desktop\file.txt')
```